# Using jquery on Marionette itemView to addClass to this.$el

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I'm trying to add a class to the enclosing tag of an itemView when a model is changed as follows

```
View.Option = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  tagName: "li",
  className: "option-item clearfix",
  template: optionsItemTpl,
  modelEvents: {
    "change": "modelChanged"
  },
  modelChanged: function() {
    console.log(this.$el);
    this.$el.addClass('success');
  }
});
```

The follow outputs the element I'm trying to add the class to

```
console.log(this.$el);
```

but the class isn't added and I just can't see why this would be.

Answer (score 2):

I copied your code to jsfiddle.  Seems like it is working as intended. console.log(this.$el) will not actually show you that at first that value has changed as it outputs [li.option-item] but as you can see it does not show its clearfix neither.  If you dig in deeper into the $el object you will see that success class is actually appended. You can also verify this by echoing this.el which is pure DOM element without jQUery wrapper.

[Check out slightly modified code on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EMWU/wb45v/12/)

And code itsself:

html:

```
<div id="conatainer"> </div>
```

javascript:

```
var View = {};
View.Option = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  tagName: "li",
  className: "option-item clearfix",
  modelEvents: {
    "change": "modelChanged"
  },
  modelChanged: function() {
    console.log("Model Changed..");
    this.$el.addClass('success');
    $("#conatainer").append(this.$el);
    console.log("Updated Views $el:")
    console.log(this.$el);
      console.log("Updated Views el:")
      console.log(this.el);

  }
});

var model = Backbone.Model.extend();
var model_instance = new model({test: 1});
console.log("Model Instance:");
console.log(model_instance)
var view = new View.Option({model: model_instance});
console.log("View: ")
console.log(view);
model_instance.set({test: 2});
```

Output:

```
Model Instance:
Object {cid="c1", attributes=Object, _changing=false, ...}
View: 
Object {options=Object, cid="view2", model=Object, ...}
Model Changed..
Updated Views $el:
[li.option-item]
Updated Views el:
<li class="option-item clearfix success">
```