# Marionette - Add class to parent ItemView tagname

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I am using Bootstrap accordion panels, and would like to add a class to the parent `panel` of the `panel-collapse`.

Basically,

```
if (child element) hasClass('panel-collapse.in') {
    this.addClass('open')
} else {
    this.removeClass('open')
}
```

Here is a snippet of my js, as well as going on a blind eye of how I thought the code would work:

```
return Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    className: "panel panel-default",
    template: panelTpl,
    events: {
       ...
       'click .panel-collapse': '_panelChange',
 },

 _panelChange: function() {
    if(element.has('div.in').length != 0) {
        element.addClass('open');
        console.log('panel opened fool');
    } else {
        element.removeClass('open');
        console.log('panel closed fool');
    }
 },
```

I followed this solution provided here: [Using jquery on Marionette itemView to addClass to this.$el](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097352/using-jquery-on-marionette-itemview-to-addclass-to-this-el)

But to no avail.

Is there a difference between `events` and `modelEvents`?

I am not sure exactly where I should put my code, or exactly how it should be written, but I assume it should be within an `event`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a difference between a view's events and a model's events. When binding handlers to a view's events like so:

```
events: {
  'click .panel-collapse': '_panelChange'
},
```

Then we're talking about events that happens in the DOM. Events on the model happens when changes etc. happens on the model. In your case though, a model is not being used.

At a glance here's a way to solve the `_panelChange` function.

```
return Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  tagName: 'li',
  className: "panel panel-default",
  template: panelTpl,
  events: {
     ...
     'click .panel-collapse': '_panelChange',
  },

  _panelChange: function(e) {
    $clickedEl = $(e.target);

    // Checks if clicked element has element with class,
    // if so, adds a class to parent element.
    // otherwise removes the class from parent element.
    if($clickedEl.has('div.in').length != 0) {
      this.$el.addClass('open');
    } else {
      this.$el.removeClass('open');
    }
  },
});
```

The approach you're using is not data driven (you're not using models), so you might want to look into that.

With a more data driven approach you may consider something like this:

1) Setup a model for each item in the accordion. This would need some different stuff like `{label: 'My accordion item 1', open: false}`.

2) When a user clicks on the accordion item, the click event handler would update the model `this.model.set('open', true);`. The view also needs to listen to it's model changes, so when it's deactivated it needs to update itself (removing the `open` class). Like this `this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:open', this.toggleMe)`.

3) Then the collection handling all of the accordions models would receive an event that a model's `open` property has changed. It would then update all other models setting the old `open` model to false (close it).

This way, all the updates to state is happening in the collections and models (data driven) and the views are only listening to them and updating themselves, except for the item view's click handler which will also update it's own model when clicked.